# Duda sobre acortar un código para matrices

Tags: java

Necesito un método que me compare los valores adyacentes dentro de una matriz siempre cuadrada y me devuelva el valor  más pequeño.

Estoy haciendo algo así (aunque todavía no esta completo) me está quedando muy largo.

¿Habría alguna forma de reducir el código, o lo sigo haciendo con if/else?,(el método `assertValue` compara dos valores y se queda con el menor).

Adjunto el código que estoy haciendo:

```
    public int  minimumAdjacentValue(int row, int column){
        cheeckRowsAndColumns(row, column);
        int value =100;    
        if(row == 0){
            if(column == 0){
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column+1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column+1]);
            } else if(column == matrix.length-1){
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column-1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column-1]);
            } else{
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column-1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column+1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column-1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column+1]);
            }                        
        } else if(column ==0){
            if(row == matrix.length-1){
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column+1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column+1]);    
            } else {
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column+1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column+1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column+1]);    
            }
        } else if(row == matrix.length-1){
             if(column == matrix.length-1){
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column-1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column-1]);
            } else if(column == 0){
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column+1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column+1]);
            } else{
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column-1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column+1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column-1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column+1]);
            }
        } else if(column == matrix.length-1){
            if(row == matrix.length-1){
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column-1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column-1]);    
            } else {
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row][column+1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row-1][column+1]);
                value = assertValue(value,matrix[row+1][column+1]);    
            }
        }    
        return value;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, esta web es para realizar preguntas sobre un tema en específico, te recomiendo que al menos intentes codificar algo y cuando tengas una duda que no te permite continuar nos la presentes o si tienes algo avanzado adjuntalo en la pregunta y con gusto te colaboraremos. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para más información. Saludos ;)

Comment: ¿Y el problema?

Comment: el hacer un método que haga eso en una matriz ya creada

Comment: Deberías indicar al menos que has intentado hacer, edita la pregunta y pega tu código como lo ha indicado Israel-ICM, así podremos ayudarte en tu problema. Normalmente las preguntas estilo 'tengo este ejercicio y quiero que me lo hagan' no son bien recibidas.

Comment: Lo siento, es que soy bastante nuevo, ya he modificado la pregunta

Comment: En realidad todo este codigo no tiene ningun sentido. a value le estas pasando un valor atras de otro, y solo se queda con el ultimo? que es lo que tratabas de hacer y que deberia hacer este codigo?

Comment: No, porque el método assertValue lo que hace es devolver el menor de dos valores, entonces lo que hago es comparar si el value es mayor o menor que el valor de la fila, si es menor el value se queda igual y sino lo cambia y asi constantemente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías probar a realizar la comprobación de esta manera. Creando una función la cual le pasas las posiciones individualmente y el array, y realizas la comprobación del mínimo adyacente al llamarla en el main.

```
   private static int comprobacionAdyacente(int col, int fil, int[][] ae) {
    int fls = ae.length;
    int Clmns = ae[0].length;

    return Stream.of(     // Realiza una lista de las posiciones
            new Point(col - 1, fil - 1), new Point(col - 1, fil), new Point(col - 1, fil + 1),
            new Point(col, fil - 1), new Point(col, fil + 1),
            new Point(col + 1, fil - 1), new Point(col + 1, fil), new Point(col + 1, fil + 1))
            .filter(p -> p.x >= 0 && p.y >= 0 && p.x < Clmns && p.y < fls)  // los mantiene en el rango de valores
            .mapToInt(p -> ae[p.y][p.x])
            .sorted()
            .findFirst()  // solicita el valor mas pequeño (el primero que encuentra)
            .orElse(-1);  // default por si algo sale mal
}
```

Y aquí te indico el main que he utilizado generando un array de 3x5, rellenado de números random y mostrándolo, de ahí puedes partir y utilizarlo como plantilla e indicar el tamaño del array que quieras.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    Random r = new Random();

    int[][] ar = new int[3][5];

    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            int rand = r.nextInt(9) + 1;
            ar[i][j] = rand;
            System.out.printf("%3d", ar[i][j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Selecciona la primera posicion: ");
    int posic1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.print("La segunda posicion: ");
    int posic2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    System.out.println("El valor minimo alrededor es " + comprobacionAdyacente(posic1, posic2, ar)); // Aquí pasamos las dos posiciones mas el array
}
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.